# How to forward emails leaving the original intact

Tags: email, forwarding, exim

I have a requirement to "copy" all emails going to person A's email to person B leaving the original intact.  If I forward the emails, they are no longer in person A's folder.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what OS and mailserver you're using.

Comment: I assumed this would be done in cPanel, thus allowing the users to use whatever OS and mail client they want.

Comment: You're running the mail server, don't you know what software it is?

Comment: Apache is a webserver, not a mailserer.

Comment: Oops...It's an Exim version 4.85

Comment: Next time, please [edit] your question to add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/aliases` and add an alias that copies to the second address:

```
A: \A, B
```

Escaping `A` means that it should be delivered to that user without treating it as an alias, which prevents an infinite loop.

If there's a webmail interface to the mail system, it may have a page where users can set up their own auto-forwarding. It probably has a "Keep a local copy" checkbox. So `A` can put `B` in their auto-forwarding list, and check that box.

Comment: Where so I make an "alias"?

Comment: In `/etc/aliases`.

Comment: I already looked at forwarding... unfortunately, some mail clients will remove the email once it has been forwarded, which is not what the user wants; she wants to somehow "copy" the email and send it to her.  I don't think it's gonna be possible the way most email clients work.  thanks for your time tho'

Comment: This forwarding is not being done by the mail client, it's done on the server. It's totally transparent to the user.

Comment: I realize that... but when the email is forwarded it will never get to the addressee, since the email client only receives what the server sends it... in other words, it's forwarded before being sent to the original addressee, right?

Comment: The "Keep local copy" option makes it send to the original addressee as well.

Comment: There is no "Keep local copy" in the cPanel email forwarding... thank you for your time anyway.  It's not worth the time we're spending on this.

Comment: I was talking about webmail. In cPanel, if it lets you edit aliases, you should use the first method I described.